# Can I drive in Spain using my U.S. (New York State) license?

Tags: europe, driving, spain, us-citizens, driving-licenses

I know I can get an IDP, but I read in some places that they recognize US Driver's Licenses specifically New York.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this *USA Today* article](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/rent-cars-madrid-35363.html) you can't.

Comment: No exceptions, if police stops you, they won't allow to continue your travel unless you have a valid license (Spanish license or international).

Comment: Could perfectly be. Sometimes there exceptions though. There is this exception on the rule that it is forbidden to drive a Dutch registered car, if you don't live in the Netherlands and that is if you drive a rental. That is why I suggested calling the big rental agencies

Comment: I live in Spain and I know how traffic police works in Spain. Don't try to drive without an international or Spanish license. It won't work, believe me :)

Comment: @Ivan Okay, I edited my answer accordingly. I assume when your say Spanish license your EU license, because I have been driving in Spain with my Belgian license and even rented a car

Comment: Well, all EU nationals can drive in Spain, of course, but I'm not refering to the law, I'm talking about the traffic police. Spain is not a good place to have problems with them and a they may not understand for instance your dutch license and may make loose a lot of time.

Comment: @Ivan: EU licenses are valid in entire EU. Period. No exceptions. Not even for Guardia Civil.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. This is an image of yesterday: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=263571470412523&set=a.138342846268720.17966.138334929602845&type=1&ref=nf Police or Guardia Civil in Spain are very agressive people, they come from a dictatorship without any filtering. I repeat: don't make them easy to stop or arrest you. Anyway, you are right: EU licenses are valid in Spain, it's up to you to make it easy or not.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, an international license is mostly a multi-lingual translation of your national drivers license.  In theory, you might avoid needing one in nations where police commonly speak English, like Scandinavia, Germany, etc., although officers might still demand one, depending upon how national laws are worded, the officer's dislike of foreigners, etc.  Spain cannot expect that its police speak English, so yes you'll need the international one.  You'll probably still need it even if the officer speaks English because their laws would be written assuming the officer might not speak English.